# C# UWP using System.IO.Directory return empty array?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

i am trying to return all the files contain in a folder in UWP application for Windows 10, the code is shown below:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Desktop";
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);  //get empty arrays
```

But, i get empty string arrays, may I know what causes this problem?

Comment: How are you trying to use these in a UWP application?

Comment: @JesseGlover "Project Centennial" allows non-WinRT applications (including C/C++ Win32 and .NET applications) to be packaged-up within UWP.

Comment: @Dai we all learn something new everyday. Thanks for the share of that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. For uwp and store apps, only the app installation and app temp folders are granted for direct access.  'Direct' means ... accesses without Windows.Storge broker process. (System.IO is 'direct'.)

If you want to access the 'outside' of your app - like as desktop, you need to ask user to pick the location by File/FolderPicker. Without the user interaction, you can't access.

However, Windows.Storage broker service provide the rich methods for file operation, and additional functions like as CommnonQuery features.
There are some exception for pictures, video folders, but the basic concept is same.

Following link may helps you. :)

[File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FilePicker

Comment: This basically breaks compatibility with any library using System.IO, because even when application has ANY access level, System.IO methods still throws UnauthorizedAccessException.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `C:\Users\Desktop` doesn't exist on the system - it would be under `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\Desktop`.

Additionally, your application might be operating in a sandbox, so all filesystem access will be virtualized to a private silo elsewhere - Windows would pretend that the directory you specified exists but says it's empty, because it doesn't want you accessing the user's files without prior permission.

Comment: the path is correct, if i use in WPF application, i could get array of string of all the files path inside that folder, so how can i remove the sandbox, and why dint Windows throw me an exception..